# How do you copy a class on to UNIX?

Tags: java, unix, intellij-idea, putty

How do you copy a class (from intelliJ) on to UNIX (using putty)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can copy and paste text, if you are talking source code. `cat > MyFile.java` is useful on the UNIX side.

If you want to transfer files, use `psftp` included with PuTTY. Your server will need to be running an accessible `sftp` server.

Connect with:

```
open host.name
```

Enter you login name and password at the prompts.

Show remote directory location with `pwd` and local location with `!pwd`.

Change remote directory with `cd` and local with `lcd`.

Upload a file with:

```
put MyFile.java
```

`mput` is also useful for transferring multiple files. Use `help` to get a list of commands and `help command` to get help on a specific command.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY may not be able to copy files. Use [OpenSSH](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) for Windows instead. This contains **scp**, a program for copying files remotely.

Comment: PuTTY comes with `pscp` and `psftp` since long ago.

Comment: That's good news!